# GET request on page removing POST information

Tags: php, rest, post, get

I have a page called test_photo.php, which people get directed to from a form after doing a POST request

```
<form id="search_photos" action="test_photo.php" method="post">
    <select name="photographer" id="photographer">
        <option selected="selected" value="x">Any Photographer</option>
    </select>

    <--Removed for clarity sake -->

    <input name="Submit" value="Search Now &gt;" id="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

on the page that we post to (test_photo.php) we have pagination to help break up the huge amount of data that gets displayed. This is handled by a GET request the url may look something like http://foobar.com/xpath/test_photo.php?page=0.

The problem is that whenever someone perform a get request on the page the POST data disappears. Does anyone know any way in which we can solve this.

Comment: The approcah to this is all wrong. POST data can't be displayed if the form is not submitted or resubmitted. If you want this to be stored across pages, use GET instead and use the GET-value to set the default-values in the dropdown-box.

Comment: We can post to the page fine, the print_r of post shows this when we head to the page:
    Array ( [LocationName] => 1 [photographer] => x [images] => x [Submit] => Search Now > ) 

its only when we do a get request on the page we have a problem as the post data does not follow through with the get request

Comment: @Artful_dodger: Yes, this is by design. Like I said, you can't have the POST-variables defined unless it's the page you just got from submitting a form. It is supposted to work this way. POST is really just the values you end up with after clicking the submit-button. If you do a simple GET-request, you did not just click any submit-buttons. You see?

Comment: Give some code from test_photo.php to look for errors. The form itself isn't enough. Also remember that, if you are uploading a file, the input tag has to contain the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @AlejandroIván: That has nothing to do with the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey, trying to rule out the obvious here.

You are mixing `GET` and `POST` in a way that is incorrect. You should only address `POST` if you have a form with values you don't want exposed and those values are no longer needed after submitting (like logging in). Here you have values that you carry on to the next page etc.

This will never work because if you post a form, the `POST`-values are only available right after you submitted the form. If you try to do a clean refresh (not reposting the form), you will see that the values are gone.

What you should do it posting the form as `POST` and then building a query of `GET`-parameters.

Like

```
page.php?page=1&photographer=1&location=3
```

This is a correct way to address filters. Just look at how Google is storing the current search-query ([google.com?q=your search](http://google.com?q=your%20search)). The rule is "values needed across different pages"? Just `GET`. This will also make it possible for people to bookmark searches or send them to other people with all the filters applied.

Comment: +1 Correct answer but I don't know if he'll understand what you're saying :)

Comment: Yep this is a better one than mine, but if he doesn't understand that Post values are not persistent, he'll be probably confused here. Anyway, +1!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the POST data does not disappear. It is there, but your submit handler probably ignores it if it sees GET data first.

As this little demo will show:

```
<?
    print_r( $_REQUEST );
?>

<form action="/path/to_this/page.php?get=yes" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="SomeVal"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But, that said, it sounds like your simplest option is to submit the data to the page without its GET parameters. I am assuming, you do not need both (i.e. you do not care what is the page number in the case of a POSTed data).

But, in any case, you should be able to view both GET and POST data.

Now, when you say "someone perform a get request on the page" - if you mean, someone pastes the URL in a browser and hits Enter, then you will never see that POST data in this case. You will only see it after the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think a GET request would destroy your POST data. Check to see if your $_POST data is intact when the "destination" page loads by adding a debug statement such as 
print_r($_POST);
to your page. It should print out the entire $_POST array to inspect.

If your browser supports such, a right mouse click may allow you to "inspect element" to see the array in a better formatted view.

You can do the same with print_r($_GET); to see what it contains as well, or any array in fact.

Comment: It does destroy it. Try posting a form, then refreshing the page (if the browser asks you do sendt the form anew, click no). The values are gone.

Comment: GET values don't destroy the POST ones. What you are telling makes no sense, because POST is only sent once when submitting a form and it does not persist across multiple page loads.

Comment: @AlejandroIván you're misunderstanding OptimusCrime, you're both kind of saying the same thing but with different words.

Answer (score 0):

GET values don't destroy POST ones, you have to understand this a little better, that's all.

When you submit your form using POST, the page that loads generates a $_POST array with the values passed. When you load another page including GET parameters, POST disappears because it is not persistent across page loads.

What you have to do is to store the values (using sessions, for example) to make them persistent. Something like:

```
<?php
    session_name("any_name_for_starting_a_session");
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST)) $_SESSION['passed_values'] = $_POST; // Store the values if POST is sent

    if (isset($_SESSION['passed_values'])) { // Getting the values if stored
        $post = $_SESSION['passed_values'];

        // Here you can work with $post ...
        //...


        // If you need to delete the stored values
        // unset($_SESSION['passed_values']);
    }
?>
```